# use Javascript to wrap all regmarks with <sup> tags unless they already have <sup> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

thanks in advance.

I am using

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
           $("body").html(
    $("body").html().replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
   );
        });
```

to add a subscript around regmarks, but if the ® marks already has the < sup >   < / up > tags, it is adding the superscript twice. Can anyone help me with add a check to stop if its already there?

update::
I ended up using this code because the answers below were interfering with the rest of my javascript.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("p,h1,h2,h3,h4, td").each(function(){
     $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;       
      </sup>').replace('<sup><sup>', '<sup>').replace('</sup></sup>', '</sup>'));
   });
 });
```

Comment: Possibly an odd question, but: why? Why are you superscripting an already superscript character?

Comment: i am updating a legacy user-generated content site that needed to add regmarks, some regmarks were previosuly superscripted and some were not. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: That still leaves the original question. Why are you *adding* superscript markup around an already superscript character, instead of *removing* the superfluous `<sup>...</sup>` when it's use in the legacy source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
$("body").html(
  $("body").html()
    .replace(/((?!<sup>\s*))&reg;((?!\s*<\/sup>))/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>') // wrap &reg; if not wrapped yet
    .replace(/((?!<sup>\s*))®((?!\s*<\/sup>))/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>') // wrap ® if not wrapped yet
);
```

**Explanation:**

Rather than doing what other folks have suggested and removing the duplicates after the fact you can build the test for the wrapped tag in the regex itself.

For example, this regex only finds the character (entity) when it is not surrounded by `SUP` tags:

`/((?!<sup>\s*))®((?!\s*<\/sup>))/gi`
and
`/((?!<sup>\s*))&reg;((?!\s*<\/sup>))/gi`

JsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/co3sy5zo/

Runnable Snippet: (uses native javascript instead of jQuery)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = 
  document.body.innerHTML
    .replace(/((?!<sup>\s*))&reg;((?!\s*<\/sup>))/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')
    .replace(/((?!<sup>\s*))®((?!\s*<\/sup>))/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>');
```

```html
<sup>&reg;</sup>
&reg;
<sup>®</sup>
®
<sup> &reg; </sup>
<sup> ® </sup>
<sup>
   &reg; 
</sup>
<sup> ® 
</sup>
"Buy more Emo&reg; Jeans!"
```

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.  Wrapping it in a $(document).ready(){} totally worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @alrjoo This doesn't work with spaces in the reg. http://jsfiddle.net/u6cqusue/1/ where my answer does http://jsfiddle.net/u6cqusue/3/

Comment: @Victory: Good point - OP did not mention whitespace between the tags, but I added \s* into the regex to handle any optional whitespace between the tags and content. Be careful: the pattern that you used is a slippery slope; you will spend lots more time debugging and maintaining code where you try to over-correct things after the fact. Better to only do the minimum work required instead of naively convert everything and try to fix later. (your code may have unintended consequences; here is one example of how your solution fails: http://jsfiddle.net/u6cqusue/5)

Comment: Thats a good counter example as well. We might as well just link to the most famous answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: great answer thanks!  The only thing I might add to someone using this is to scope it down as far as you can.  Starting from $("body").html() is quite a hit, if you have something like a "main-content" region or some consistent top level tag that you can set as the top level, it's super fast and works perfectly!!  Thanks :-)

Comment: This seems what I have been looking for but I cannot implement this on my WP page without getting a: Unexpected string literal 'body'. Expected a parameter pattern or a ')' in parameter list. error. :-(

Answer (score 0):

There are more efficient ways to do this, but the easiest way is just to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").html(
       $("body").html().replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace('<sup><sup>','<sup>').replace('</sup></sup>','</sup>');
   );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add more replace

```
$("body").html().replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace('<sup><sup>', '<sup>').replace('</sup></sup>', '</sup>')
```

Comment: Won't work with spaces or newlines that were added before the replace.

Comment: he just replaced the old one, so there is no white space or new lines

Comment: Try it on  "<sup> &reg; </sup>"; You would want to do something like `$("sup > sup").each(function () { $(this).parent("sup").html("&reg;");`

Answer (score 0):

Without using a regular expression solution, you could wrap the replace statement in another replace statement that replaces `<sup><sup>` with `<sup>` and `</sup></sup>` with `</sup>`.

Another method would be to search for `&reg;` with a space before or after, assuming there will be a space if there isn't a tag present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find "sup" with child "sup" then set the parent sup to have "®" for html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").html(
  $("body").html().replace(/&reg;/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>').replace(/®/gi, '<sup>&reg;</sup>')); // this will break in script tags and a few other places.
  $("sup sup").each(function () {  // find sup with child sup
      $(this).parent("sup").html("&reg;"); 
  });
 });
```

This works for when the original has spaces around the reg "  <sup>®</sup> "