# How to remove a tag and its contents from a string in javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, string

I have a string like this:
      Name
      <sup>a,b,c</sup>

I got this from the text() method of jQuery, like:

```
var str = $(this).text();
```

where `$(this)` is a wrapper `div`.

The output of `str` will be something like : **Name<sup>a,b,c</sup>**.

I want a short way to extract just "Name" from the `str` variable.
I don't want to change the `DOM` e.g. by using `.remove()` or `.empty()` etc. and I also can't use `replace()` or s`ubstr()` as the lenghts of the contents in the `sup tag` is variable.

I have seen some regex and DOM manipulation functions but again this is not something I could use.
Any suggestions of what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain why you cannot use regexes and replace? Because using a regex and returning just the 'non sup' part, would be the easiest way to do so.

Comment: The only way I can think to do it would be regex.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello DevMan**

I am afraid that this question has already been answered in another post or at least is an initial point for this one. Take a look and see if this covers your inquire. Cheers Mate!

**[Previous Answered Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116372/use-javascript-to-wrap-all-regmarks-with-sup-tags-unless-they-already-have-su)**